# CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE variable won't silence file(INSTALL ...)

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have a part of code in CMake. It should copy files from `source` folder to a `destination` folder and I want it to be silent.

According to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html) `set (CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE NEVER)`  should make it quiet. **But it doesn't.**

This is the code:

```
# Silence installation messages
set (SAVE_CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE}) # Saving the state
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE NEVER)
message("CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE}") # NEVER

file(INSTALL ${SOURCE} DESTINATION ${DEST} USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS)
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE ${SAVE_CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE}) # Restitute

message("CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE}") # <empty>
```

It is not silent, it prints out every file with
`-- Installing: /some/destination/path` and `-- Up-to-date: /some/destination/path`

Any ideas how to silence that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html) tells that variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE` affects **only** on `install()` command:

> Specify verbosity of installation script code generated by the `install()` command

The command `file(INSTALL)` is not affected by that variable.

If you want `file(INSTALL)` to be quiet, then use `file(COPY)` instead (the other parameters would be the same).

---

The part about `file(INSTALL)` describes only **internal implementation** of verbosity:

> (using the `file(INSTALL)` command)

For every `install()` invocation in `CMakeLists.txt` CMake adds to the installation script `cmake_install.cmake` a call to `file(INSTALL)`. That call uses some *undocumented* parameters, and one of these parameters specifies verbosity. The undocumented parameters are NOT described in the user's documentation and should NOT be used outside of CMake itself.

That is, when read the documentation, a user could simply **omit** the part about `file(INSTALL)`. Not sure why internal implementation is ever described in the docs.

---

E.g. the call to

```
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/text.txt DESTINATION share)
```

generates the following `file(INSTALL)` call in the `cmake_install.cmake`:

```
file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share" TYPE FILE FILES "/home/tester/tests/cmake/text.txt")
```

with **undocumented** option TYPE.

The same call but after setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE` variable to `NEVER` generates instead

```
file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share" TYPE FILE MESSAGE_NEVER FILES "/home/tester/tests/cmake/text.txt")
```

with **undocumented** keyword `MESSAGE_NEVER`.

Once again, NEVER use these undocumented options in the normal CMake projects.